# Form.ShowDialog() return 'No'?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I declared a form in a c# auto updater programme

```
SharpUpdateDownloadForm form = new SharpUpdateDownloadForm(update.Uri, update.MD5, applicationInfo.ApplicationIcon);
//applicationInfo.Context is 'myForm1'     
DialogResult result = form.ShowDialog(applicationInfo.context);
```

what is the reason that 'form.ShowDialog(applicationInfo.context)' return 'NO as the result ?

Comment: What do you set the dialog result to before you close the dialog?

Comment: sorry , @John I cant understand what you asking.

Comment: @YureshKarunanayake: Does your from have `CancelButton` property set? and how do you close your form?

Comment: No , this form showing the status of the download.It have only a label 'Downloading' and a Progress Bar

Comment: How this form get closed?

Comment: It automatically close when download completes. download is done in a background thread

Comment: I don’t see how the proposed duplicate answers this question.

Comment: _"It automatically close when download completes"_  - how?

Comment: If this is what you're using, you can look at the source code to see why it's returning `No`: https://github.com/henryxrl/SharpUpdate/blob/master/SharpUpdate/SharpUpdateDownloadForm.cs

Comment: The fact that it is a `SharpUpdateDownloadForm` is an important detail

Answer (score 2):

The `DialogResult` will show you the outcome of the modal operation that is performed on the form. The most common way to determine the result is with the button the user has pressed. In case of `DialogResult.No`, the user has pressed the *No* button (usually on a *Yes/No* or *Yes/No/Cancel* dialog).

Having said that, eventually it is up to the form to determine the result it returns. In case the form closes itself, it will automatically determine a result. Which result that is depends on the implementation of the form. So you should check `SharpUpdateDownloadForm` for what it does or referer to the respective documentation (if available).